# npm package contains node_module folder when i install it from our private hosted gitlab

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

we are using the package registry functionality from our private hosted gitlab.

i've created a small project which publishes the package in a ci-pipeline. when i verify this on gitlab, it says the package has ~4 kb in size. The content of the packages looks just fine (no node_modules folder).

But when i install this package in another project with `npm install MY-PACKAGE`, i have a "node_modules" folder inside my package.

meaning: node_modules/{MY-PACKAGE}/node_modules/

Inside this second node_modules folder are the dependencies listed in the package.json.

Can anyone tell me why this happens? and how i can get rid of it?